# Strange behavior of CGLayerCreateWithContext on iPad 2 vs on the New iPad?

Tags: ios, uiview, core-graphics, cglayer, graphicscontext

In a Single View App, FooView is the main view.  In FooView's `drawRect`, if I do

```
if (!self.layer1) {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    NSLog(@"current context is drawRect is %@", context);

    self.layer1 = CGLayerCreateWithContext(context, self.bounds.size, NULL);
    NSLog(@"layer1 is %@", self.layer1);

    self.context1 = CGLayerGetContext(self.layer1);

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(self.context1, [[UIColor orangeColor] CGColor]);
}

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

NSDate *start = [NSDate date];
CGContextDrawLayerAtPoint(context, CGPointZero, self.layer1);
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = -[start timeIntervalSinceNow];
NSLog(@"It took %f to draw", timeInterval);
```

And I am using a `CADisplayLink` to invoke a method that calls `[self.view setNeedsDisplay]` in the view controller, so that `drawRect` is invoked every 1 frame, or 5 frame, or 20 frame, using the `frameInterval` property.

On iPad2, the time to draw when the CGLayer is filled with hundreds of 6x6 points rectangle, is about 0.011 to 0.012 second, as printed by the NSLog statement.  This is capable of 60fps.  (60fps is 0.01666 second per frame)

If I change the line to:

```
    self.layer1 = CGLayerCreateWithContext(NULL, self.bounds.size, NULL);
```

(using `NULL` instead of `context`).  Then the time is about 0.014 second, which is still good for 60 fps.

But on the New iPad, the opposite is happening: if `context` was used on that line, then the time is a whopping 0.17 second... which is not good for even 6 fps.  If `NULL` is used, then the time is 0.038, which is not good for 60 fps, but at least it is good for 20 fps, which is still acceptable.  Does any one know why it is behaving like this, and how to make it work well or work better on all platform of iPad, iPad 2 and the New iPad?

If calling `CGLayerCreateWithContext` with `NULL` gave a GPU cached graphics context, and calling with `context` gave a bitmap context, then why on iPad 2, it is actually faster if calling `CGLayerCreateWithContext` with `context`?

(I am using iOS 5.1.1 on the New iPad, and iOS 5.1 on iPad 2... which shouldn't be that much a difference... and I don't want to upgrade iPad 2 so that I can have another device with a different iOS version to test against my app).

Comment: What leads you to believe you can safely call `CGLayerCreateWithContext` without providing a context? The documentation makes no such guarantee.

Comment: that's because at first, I use `CGLayerCreateWithContext` inside of `viewDidAppear` and `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` to get the context and supply it to `CGLayerCreateWithContext`, but later on, I found that context is actually `null`.  Or else, how do you supply it with a context that is good for getting a CGLayer that is cached on the GPU?  Seemingly if in `drawRect`, it could be a BitMapContext in RAM, as shown by the slow draw time of 0.17 second